# How I use preg_match() to get my data duplicate

Tags: php, preg-match

I use `preg_match` to get data

At my `$data` I want to `preg_match` srarch `hidden%22+name%3D%22` for get
 `bbb81b5` and `3413f12f5700156bac65e50bf07a732e`

```
preg_match ( "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden%22+name%3D%22\" value=\"(.*)\">", $data, $sc);
```

but not work `echo $sc[1]` is empty. This my data.

```
$data = '
+%2F%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cinput+type%3D%22hidden%22+name%3D%22bbb81b5%22+value%3D%223413f12f5700156bac65e50bf07a732e%22+%2F%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cinput+type%3D%22hidden%22+name%3D%22seqnum%22+value%3D%2212646900%22
';
```

My data from Httpfox post data to SMF2.0
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Your data doesn't contain any input tag!

Comment: Please add some coherent code.

Comment: You need [delimiters for the pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and rather use [negation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) than greedy dot: `preg_match(` [`'/<input type="hidden" name="aa159ca" value="([^"]*)"/'`](https://regex101.com/r/pA9kB9/2)... `var_dump($sc[1])`

Comment: @bobble bubble show me for example please

Comment: @sammy please provide your actual testdata that you're processing.

Comment: @bobble bubble look my edit post please.

Comment: Well, seems urlencoded data. [See this demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/521108)

Comment: @bobble bubble Thank you so much and I'm sorry about my data so this is new $data = ' +%2F%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cinput+type%3D%22hidden%22+name%3D%22bbb81b5%22+value%3D%223413f12f5700156bac65e50bf07a732e%22+%2F%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cinput+type%3D%22hidden%22+name%3D%22seqnum%22+value%3D%2212646900%22 ';

Comment: @bobble bubble please help me again.

Comment: Your testdata [works fine in demo](https://eval.in/521229).

Comment: @bobble bubble Thank you so much, At new $data " bbb81b" not fixed, It change every time so I can't get  value="\**([^"]*?)\**"/ , what should I do ?

Comment: Whence can one know the values it could be if you don't provide all the relevant details in your question? You can try [word characters like in this demo](https://eval.in/521656).

Comment: Thank you very much. and I want you look my new topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510667/curl-auto-post-in-smf-2-0